# How to calculate permissions for chmod command?

Tags: unix, permissions, chmod

After a lot of reading, I still don't understand how to use chmod. My main question is what do the numbers mean? I am new to Unix and am doing some emergency fixes on our web server and am being asked to fix the permissions for some files. I don't understand what I need to do to make the files accessible.

Can someone provide some help here?

EDIT: Thanks for the great answers everyone. Unfortunately, I was in a panic and didn't read them in time and we ended up losing our client.. Hard to choose any single answer but I chose the one that I understood best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 permission types:

- User (permissions applying to the file's owner)
- Group (permissions applying to the file's group)
- Other (permissions applying to everyone else)

For each of these types, you can allow 3 things:

- Ability to read (note that you need read permissions on a directory to list it)
- Ability to write
- Ability to execute

If you say:

```
chmod 755 some_file
```

It gets broken down like this:

```
User  Group  Other
7     5      5      (octal value,  base-8)
111   101    101    (binary value, base-2 or binary)
RWX   RWX    RWX

where: R - Read, W - Write, X - eXecute
```

So that command would mean that the owner gets all permissions, but group members, and others can only read and execute.

There's another input format with chmod that's handy, and doesn't require you to do conversion to binary in your head. As an example, to add execute permission for user:

```
chmod u+x some_file
```

To remove those permissions, you would say

```
chmod u-x some_file
```

You can replace 'u' with 'u', 'g', or 'o' (user, group, other respectively), and 'x' with 'r', 'w', or 'x' (you get the idea).

You have to be careful with this. If you did:

```
chmod -R 777 some_directory
```

And that file contained sensitive configuration data, then you just gave 'other' (i.e. the outside world) full read permissions (meaning the web server may serve up this information).

It would also be worthwhile for you to have a look at the `chown` command as well.

Comment: also: I recommend trying out `ls -al`, as this shows you very cleanly everything discussed here.

Comment: To be complete, you might want to mention the setUID/setGID bits.

Comment: To be honest, I've never used them, and can't speak as an expert on the topic. Maybe I'll revise if I get time.

Comment: Briefly: Options are u+-s and g+-s. If set, they cause the effective user ID and/or the group ID of the executable's process to be set to that of the file when the file is executed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't understand the numbers, don't use them:

```
chmod u=rw,go=r file
```

That will set the permissions on the file to read and write for the user, and readonly for group and others.  You can use `+` to add a permission:

```
chmod ug+x file
```

(so now the user and the group can execute the file), and you can use `-` to remove a permission:

```
chmod g-x file
```

(so now the members of the group can't execute the file).

If you want to use the numbers, there are two sets of facts you need to know:

1. The numbers are octal (digits 0..7), and the first digit (of three) represents the permissions for the user, the second digit represents the permissions for the group, and the third and final digit represents the permissions for others.
2. The octal numbers use three bits, and the values for each bit are:

   - 4 — read
   - 2 — write
   - 1 — execute

Therefore, using permissions like:

```
chmod 640 file
```

can be split up into `6` for the user, 4 for the group and 0 for others.  The `6` which is `4 + 2` (or `4|2`) means 'read' and 'write' permission for the owner; the `4` for the group means group members can read the file; and `0` for others means that other people cannot access the file.

In the context of a directory, 'execute' is better termed 'access', meaning someone with access to the directory can use files in the directory if the file permissions permit, and the user knows the name.  With read permission on a directory too, you can see a list of the files in the directory; with write permission on a directory, you can create new files or delete existing ones.

Note that a read-only file can be deleted if the user doing the deleting has write permission on the directory.  Commands such as `rm` provide protection as a courtesy, rather than relying on the kernel to protect the user of the command.

I've not covered 3 more bits on the permissions, which appear before the user permissions.  You don't need to worry about those while the basic permissions are causing you confusion, but the SUID or set UID bit (4), SGID or set GID bit (2), and the sticky bit (1) can be useful for advanced permission controls.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this online toy](http://www.onlineconversion.com/html_chmod_calculator.htm) out or Google for [numerous tutorials](http://catcode.com/teachmod/). The numbers give the owner's permissions, the group's permissions, and other peoples' permissions in octal format.

Answer (score 0):

Other people have provided good explanations of how to decode the octal representation of permissions. This just covers how to solve what your underlying problem probably is.

The problem you are experiencing is most likely that some files are unable to be read by someone accessing your website.  If your website is organized reasonably, all the publicly accessible files are in a single directory without any non-public files in that directory. If that is the case, you can use the following to change all the files in and under the current directory such that they are readable:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod oug+r {} \;
```

Having the read permission for "other" (o+r) on the directories will allow someone to read the contents of the directories on your website as a directory. You will need to determine if this is something you desire to have be the case and/or if doing so is consistent with the policies of your organization. Usually someone can read a specifically named file --if the file has the appropriate read permission set-- without the need to read the directory. To set the read permission on directories it is:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod oug+r {} \;
```

However, it is also likely that you want all such directories not to be read by everyone, only the user and group.  In such case:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod ug+r o-r {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have provided plenty of explanation on permissions. If you're in a hurry and just want to figure out what permissions to use with the chmod command, I'd check out one of the many online calculators so you don't have to waste time while your boss is breathing down your neck.

- http://permissions-calculator.org/
- http://mintools.neocities.org/#/unix-permissions-calculator
- http://mistupid.com/internet/chmod.htm

I'd still recommend learning the basics after though...